# For what Alt in Monoid instance needed?

Tags: haskell, applicative, monoids, alternative-functor

In Monoid and Semigroup instances of Alternative Alt used.

Why we can't write instance without it?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
instance Alternative f => Semigroup (f a) where
  (<>) = <|>

instance Alternative f => Monoid (f a) where
  mempty = empty
```

And if we can write that, can we then replace Alternative with (Monoid (f a), Applicative f) in functions?

Comment: Where did you find this definition? I wouldn't expect it to be in the standard library.

Comment: I find it [there](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/Data.Semigroup.Internal.html#line-321)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use it for deriving `Monoid` for any `Alternative`

```
{-# Language DerivingVia #-}

data F a = ..
  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
  via Alt F a

instance Functor     F where ..
instance Applicative F where ..
instance Alternative F where ..
```

[`Alt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Alt) is a newtype for good reason as there are many ways to describe `Monoid` behaviour for an applied type `f a`. For example [`Applicative` lifting: `Ap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Ap).

```
{-# Language DerivingVia #-}

data G a = ..
  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid, Num, Bounded)
  via Ap G a

instance Functor     G where ..
instance Applicative G where ..
```

The instances you give are maximally overlapping, the `Monoid` instance of any applied type  is now forced to be the `Alternative` instance, completely ignoring the `a` parameter.

There are many instances where this would not be correct, for example `Semigroup a => Semigroup (Maybe a)` is not the same as the `Semigroup` you would get from `Alternative Maybe`.

It is possible using a rather new feature `QuantifiedConstraints` to quantify over the argument of a type constructor `forall x. Monoid (f x)`. This is not the same as `Alternative` but similar

```
{-# Language QuantifiedConstraints #-}
..

type Alternative' :: (Type -> Type) -> Constraint

class    (forall x. Monoid (f x)) => Alternative' f
instance (forall x. Monoid (f x)) => Alternative' f
```

Comment: What's with the standalone instances like `instance Functor F`? Does `DerivingVia` somehow imply an instance implementation?

Comment: Yes when you derive via `Alt F a` this requires `Alternative F` → `Applicative F` → `Functor F` instances, and `Ap G a` requires `Applicative G`. These signify user-written instances but a cool feature in the latest base (4.17) has the ability to derive these instances for some cases: [`deriving (Functor, Applicative, Alternative) via Generically1 F`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t:Generically1).

Answer (score 2):

You use the [**`(<|>) :: Alternative f => f a -> f a -> f a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--124--62-) and [**`empty :: Alternative f => f a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:empty). As the signatures suggest, these are defined for items of type `Applicative f => f a`. You thus can only use these functions to process such items, and this thus requires that if you work with an `f a`, for eample to define `mempty :: f a` with `mempty = empty`, then that requires that `f` is a member of the [**`Alternative`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative).

That being said, while a lot data types *can* have a `Semigroup` and `Monoid` instance defined as how the `Alternative` is implemented, this is not per se the best instance. Yes `Alternative` is a *monoid* on applicative functors, but that should not per se be *the* monoid instance on these data types.

Answer (score 1):

If the instances you propose existed in that form, *every* type that matches `f a` would immediately defer to it. That includes types where it makes sense, but consider

```
newtype ResultsSum a = ResultsSum {funToSum :: a -> Int}

instance Semigroup (ResultsSum a) where
  ResultsSum p <> ResultsSum q = ResultsSum $ \x -> p x + q x
```

Unfortunately though, `ResultsSum a` matches `f a`. But it is not an `Alternative`; it isn't even a functor, and can't be (rather, it is [`Contravariant`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html)). However, the compiler doesn't take that into account when resolving instances: it just sees two instance declarations whose heads both purport to enable `ResultsSum` being a semigroup, which triggers an ambiguous-instance error.

Granted, this example *could* be addressed with `{-# OVERLAPPING #-}` pragmas, but it's always best to avoid instance overlaps as they can lead to strange. It's unnecessary, since you can also also derive those instances `via` the `Alternative` one. Though I personally would actually rather do it the other way around: define the `Monoid` instance first and then `Alternative` in terms of it.